# Openshift mongodb connection url

Tags: node.js, mongodb, url, openshift, database

I'm trying to put my graduation project that has been running on my raspberry pi for months on openshift so I can use my pi for other purposes.

I've transfered all nodejs code. I've mongodumped and restored the database from PI to openshift. So I've kinda everything up and running except from the database connection and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is what I have in my nodejs code (config/database.js)

```
module.exports = {
  // 'url': 'mongodb://username:password@myraspberrypiIP:27017/trackmyride'
  //  ABOVE LINE WORKS - OPENSHIFT CAN CONNECT TO MY LOCAL DATABASE

  //  ALL LINES BELOW ARE THINGS I TRIED, BUT NODEJS SERVER CAN NEVER START
  // 'url': 'mongodb://$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT/'
  // 'url': 'mongodb://username:password@OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST:OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT/cruizerserver'
  // 'url': 'OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL/cruizerserver'
  // 'url': 'mongodb://admin:password@127.*.**.***:27017/cruizerserver'
  // 'url': OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL+'cruizerserver'

  'url': process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":"
  + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@"
  + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':'
  + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/'
  + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
};
```

(passwords/username/* are placeholders for stackoverflow)

Does anybody have a clue what I'm doing wrong.
Server and project work fine when using the first line (connecting to the DB on my raspberryPI at home) but server refuses to start when I replace it by one of the bottom lines. Even when they are copy pasted from openshift's documentation.
https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-mongodb-on-nodejs-on-openshift/

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 4):

On OpenShift, you don't have to build the url yourself.  Just get it from the environment variables OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME.

```
url:  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME
```

Combining these 2 env variables will form something like this:

```
mongodb://admin:LUXXXXXXX-YI@XXXX0f534382ecf0d2000095-your_domain.rhcloud.com:52821/your_app_name
```

Comment: I tried both this:  
`'url': process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;`  
and because that did not work I also tried to hardcode it like this:  
`'url': 'mongodb://admin:8************@******007628e***********-cruizerserver-cruizer.rhcloud.com:27017/cruizerserver';`  
  
But still neighter of those gets my app to launch. :(

Comment: Then there might be something else is incorrect there.  What's the error in the log?  You can access the log by logging in using ssh (the command is on the right side of your openshift web console screen.  Once you login, cd app-root/logs/ and view the file nodejs.log

Answer (score 2):

We can use **openshift environment variables** to build the connection url.
Example.

```
  // default to a 'localhost' configuration:
  var connection_string = '127.0.0.1:27017/YOUR_APP_NAME';
  // if OPENSHIFT env variables are present, use the available connection info:
  if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
    connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
  };
  //Connect to mongodb using mongoose library
  mongoose.connect(connection_string);
 };
```

Comment: Is `OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST` now `MONGODB_SERVICE_HOST` in OpenShift Pro?

Comment: @user1063287 sorry I'm not sure about that,because I haven't tried  openshift pro.

Comment: thanks, for reference, i have found setup is different in OpenShift 3, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50212058 I will post answer there soon.